# where can i find the default 404 error page for windows sharepoint service 2.0

Tags: sharepoint

Where can i find the default htm file, mapped to show the 404 error in *Sharepoint service 2.0*. Currently whenever the request for a site hits the 404 error, it goes to the default page, but the point to note here is, which is not the one we set in IIS custom error option.

My requirement here is to make few modification in the 404 error page.  I tried mapping the request to a custom error page with `<customErros>` tag in *web.config*. But unfortunately, its still showing the default 404 error page.  When i checked the viewsource of the error page i can see some comments like, `res://shdocvw.dll/http_404.htm#http://www.DocURL.com/bar.htm`

Any idea about this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to do this but this entry looks quite reasonable: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jingmeili/archive/2007/04/08/how-to-create-your-own-custom-404-error-page-and-handle-redirect-in-sharepoint-2007-moss.aspx

Basically when you install WSS it hi-jacks IIS. You can still do most of the things you would expect but you need to go through the Central Administration pages and the XML files that control many aspects of SharePoint.

Comment: Hi Dan,
I was just trying to implement the solution given in the link provided by you. I was trying to create a console application to set the 404 page with the following code -
SPWebApplication webApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(webApplicationUri);
webApplication.FileNotFoundPage = "my404.html"; //*

Comment: I added the microsoft.sharepoint.dll reference to access the Windows sharepoint services 2.0.  But it looks like the dll version(11.0.6361.0) which i am using is not having support for "SPWebApplication".  Is there any other way i can achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, the article I linked to refers to MOSS which runs on WSS 3.0. I've only just spotted your question is for WSS 2.0.